# jquery validate depends not working consistently

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a textbox with a required depends that always returns true, when the page loads, if I click submit it will mark the textbox as required, but if I enter anything in the textbox the depends stops working and it marks it as valid even through the depends always returns true.

In other words, is there a way to mark it as invalid unless the textbox contains a specific word?

here' the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#testForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    partSearchName: {
                        required:
                        {
                            depends: function (element) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

and here's the form:

```
    <form action="/Pricing/TestValBare" id="testForm" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="partSearchName" placeholder="-- Search for a part --" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-primary" id="subBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </form>
```

versions:
jquery 3.3.1
jquery validate 1.17.0

Comment: The code you posted contains a validation rule that seems to "depend" on nothing.  It's always `required`.

Comment: ohhh I see, so how could I always mark it as invalid unless the textbox contains a specific word for example?

Comment: You need to make a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method with a function that checks for this word.

Comment: that's it, perfect, thanks!